# Karma.conf.js does not exist

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I just reinstalled node from scratch. I also installed `yeoman`, `generator-angular`, and `karma`.

After generating a project with `yo angular`, I can successfully `grunt serve`. However, whenever I try `grunt test`, the following error is thrown:

`karma.conf.js does not exist`

However, `karma.conf.js` does indeed exist in the generated test directory. Why would this happen?

Comment: did you `bower install` and `npm install`?

Comment: Yes -- yeoman (or more precisely, the generator-angular) does that automatically when generating the scaffold ...     "I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself".

Comment: same error as well, annoying !

Comment: once i added karma, this worked. npm install karma

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gruntfile.js refers to karma.conf.js in the root-dir.
The Angular generator puts it in the test-directory, so you'll need to update Gruntfile.js

```
// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }
}
```

There's also a problem when running grunt test with this generated karma.conf.js. It will say

```
test/karma.conf.js:63
    colors: true,
    ^^^^^^
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Reason: comma missing after 'singleRun: false'.

Comment: Also, if you generate angular with the --coffee command, you must change the Gruntfile karama.conf.js to karma.conf.coddee

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem but I was using CoffeeScript. It turned out that the CoffeeScript for karma.conf.js wasn't being created. karma.conf.coffee was placed properly in the test folder but it wasn't being compiled. So in my gruntfile (under the coffee task) I replaced this...

```
  test: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'test/spec',
      src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
      dest: '.tmp/spec',
      ext: '.js'
    }]
  }
```

With this...

```
      test: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'test/spec',
      src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
      dest: '.tmp/spec',
      ext: '.js'
    },
    {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'test',
      src: 'karma.conf.coffee',
      dest: 'test',
      ext: '.conf.js'
    }]
  }
```

All I did was make sure that the karma.conf.coffee compiled in the test directory.

This worked but I was still getting errors because in karma.conf.coffee some of the files had incorrect extensions ('cs' instead of 'coffee'), for these 3 lines in particular.

```
  'app/scripts/**/*.cs'
  'test/mock/**/*.cs'
  'test/spec/**/*.cs'
```

I just changed the extensions to coffeescript (and removed the mock folder,as I wasn't using it).

```
  'app/scripts/**/*.coffee'
  'test/spec/**/*.coffee'
```

after that, the builds and test worked. I'm new to Yeoman so I'm not sure if this could have easily been avoided, but it's what I had to do to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't even find karma.conf.js. However, I realized if you do

```
grunt --force
```

you will be able to get more info and you might get what is going on inside

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
08 09 2015 13:16:33.928:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-phantomjs-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
08 09 2015 13:16:33.939:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-jasmine".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
Warning: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine) Used --force, continuing.
```

Finally, I was able to figure it out what I missed.

Hope this help.